# Custom Options of Configurable product do not display in email

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, custom-options, sales-order

I have an extension that do not offer any support so i am trying to fix by my own.
So far what i did is locate the file that is responsible to render the custom options as this is my issue, it is located in `Model/Attributes.php`

The extension is about dropship so it is sending emails to suppliers , if the product is associated to a `supplier_test` and there is a new order with this product inside.
Problem is that if the product is configurable it will not send in the emails any custom options that this order include.
If it is simple it will work ok.

Here is the code of `Attributes.php` if someone can help i would really appreciate.
This is function 1:

```
public function getAllAttributes($product) {
    $entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getEntityType('catalog_product');
    $entityTypeId = $entityType->getEntityTypeId();
    $attribute_mas = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter($entityTypeId)->getItems();
    $product_attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());

    foreach ($attribute_mas as $attribute) {
        $data = $attribute->getData();
        $frontend_input = $data['frontend_input'];
        $frontend_label = $data['frontend_label'];
        $attribute_code = $data['attribute_code'];
        if ($attribute_code == 'sku' || $attribute_code == 'price')
            continue;
        if ($frontend_input == 'select') {
            $value = $product_attribute ->getAttributeText($attribute_code);
        } else {
            $value = $product_attribute->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($product_attribute);
        }
        if ($value == '' || is_array($value) || $frontend_label == '')
            continue;
        $attributes["attribute_" . $attribute_code] = $value;   
    }

    return $attributes;
}
```

Function2:

```
public function getAllCustomOptions($item) {
        $customOptions = $item->getProductOptions();
        $customOptionsMas = array();
        if(isset($customOptions['options'])){               
                $customOptionsWithSku = array();
                if (isset($customOptions['options'])) {
                    foreach ($customOptions['options'] as $option) {
                        $key = $option['label'];    
                        $customOptionsMas[$key] = $option['value'];
                        //$customOptionsWithSku[$key] = $option['sku'];
                    }
                }
                //$this->customOptions = $customOptionsWithSku;
        }
        if(isset($customOptions['additional_options'])){                    
                if (isset($customOptions['additional_options'])) {
                    foreach ($customOptions['additional_options'] as $option) {
                        $key = $option['label'];
                        $customOptionsMas[$key] = $option['value'];
                    }
                }   
        } 

        if(isset($customOptions['bundle_options'])){                    
                if (isset($customOptions['bundle_options'])) {
                    foreach ($customOptions['bundle_options'] as $option) { 
                        $key = $option['label'];
                        $optionValue = "";
                        foreach($option['value'] as $val){
                            $optionValue .= $val['title'] ." ". $val['qty'] . "x<br/>";
                        }
                        $customOptionsMas[$key] = $optionValue;
                    }
                }   
        } 
        if(isset($customOptions['info_buyRequest']['super_attribute'])){
                $super_attributes = $customOptions['info_buyRequest']['super_attribute'];
                foreach ($super_attributes as $label => $option){
                    $frontendlabel = Mage::getModel('supplier/supplier')->getAttributeLabel($label);
                    $frontendvalue = Mage::getModel('supplier/supplier')->getOptionValue($option);
                    $customOptionsMas[$frontendlabel] = $frontendvalue;
                }
        }   
        return $customOptionsMas;
}
```

and there is last function that from what i see it is connected with `function2`

```
public function getCustomOptions($item){
    $customOptionsMas = $this->getAllCustomOptions($item);
    $ret = "";
    if (!empty($customOptionsMas)) {
        foreach ($customOptionsMas as $k => $v) {
            if ($v) {
                $ret .= $k . ": " . $v . "<br/>";
            }
        }
        $ret .= "";
    }

    return $ret;
}
```